# How can I update 1 Column in SQL with different formula

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Here is my table table name is "loan"

```
ID(int)        Loan Amount(Decimal)        Initial Amount(decimal)            Interest(Decimal)

1                   100000                       0                               5

2                   230000                       0                               10

3                   150000                       0                               2
```

I want to update all the value in "Initial Amount" column. I will add the result of (loan amount x interest rate)

Example Computation

```
100,000 x .05% = 5,000
```

then the value of 5,000 will update to "inital amount"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
update table
    set `initial amount` = `Loan Amount` * (`Interest Rate` / 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update your_table
set `initial amount` = `loan amount` * (`interest rate`/100.0)
```

Comment: can i ask again @juergen d 
can i add condition to query if the updated value will be greater than to loan amount it will not update or i will just make it same to loan amount value

Comment: Used sql server syntax on my first take on the answer.  Yours had it.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to update the value ? you can always get the Initial Amount(decimal) value 
with above data.The initial amount column can be logically created, and the value will always change depends on the loan amount and interest, so my suggestion is create the column when u need it.

```
select ID, [Loan Amount], [Interest Rate], 
(([Loan Amount] * [Interest Rate])/ 100) as [Initial Amount] 
from YourTable
```

Comment: the value of initial amount is changing every 15days so i think i need a column for checking the latest value

Comment: @Denmark if the column is changing every 15 days, I think cyan's answer would be the best one.  You'd always have fresh data this way. (+1)

Comment: Why i got error? it's say Erorr in Line 1
@paqogomez what did you say this is best? Im saying of changing value is every 15days the initial value is changing because the user will pay every 15days so i need the last value of the user's pay.... then why its best?